# Greasemonkey in newsfox

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, greasemonkey

I have an annoying feed which I would like to do some url corrections in order to see inside newsfox bigger images.

Is it possible to configure a greasmonkey to load and be triggered when I view a post inside newsfox reader ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You currently cannot run GM scripts on Newsfox pages, because Newsfox opens in a *chrome* URI (chrome://newsfox/ ...).

I'm not going to install Newsfox to see, but if it happens to load a page's content into an iFrame, then any scripts written **for that page** will usually fire on the iFramed content.

Information Current as of GM 0.9.5 and FF 4.0.1, but is not likely to change soon.

Answer (score 0):

NewsFox puts article content into a frame with URL `about:blank`. You can try creating a GreaseMonkey script that will run on `about:blank` pages but I am all but sure that it will work.